# HTML: Can always the same identifier be used for name and id attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically the "name" attribute is used in server-side programming (name/value pairs are sent in requests) and the "id" attribute is used in client-side programming (i.e. Javascript and CSS).

But both fulfill essentially the same function - provide a unique identification of an element. And to complicate things not too much, it is useful if a thing has only one identifier.

Therefore the question(s) - for tags that need both "id" and "name":

Is there any reason to choose different identifiers for the name and id attributes? Are there any use-cases for which different identifiers are required? Are there any differences in syntax? (for example you can use "myarray[123]" for the name attribute and PHP will understand that correctly and create an array, can that also be used in a similar manner for id-attributes in Javascript or CSS - and if not, is that a syntax-error or is it simply a valid identifier with brackets in it?) Are both case-sensitive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any reason to choose different identifiers for the name and id attributes?

Yes. IDs must be unique, names don't have to be. Names must be the same for members of a radio group, so they can't all have the same id—well, they can in practice but accessing the elements by ID will be problematic. And if you don't access them by ID, why have it?

> Are there any use-cases for which different identifiers are required?

Yes, radio buttons. Only one can have an id that is the same as its name. But otherwise, there are few restrictions, such as than never give form controls the name or id of a method or property of the form itself, like "submit", as it will mask the same–named property of the form.

Also, names "`_charset_`" and "`isindex`" are [special](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute).

> Are there any differences in syntax? (for example you can use "myarray[123]" for the name attribute and PHP will understand that correctly and create an array, can that also be used in a similar manner for id-attributes in Javascript or CSS - and if not, is that a syntax-error or is it simply a valid identifier with brackets in it?)

Yes. The rules for [*name*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute) and [*id*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) attribute values are similar but an ID must not contain spaces (and some values for *name* are special, see above). There were more restrictions on id attributes in HTML4 (e.g. ids couldn't start with a number), but in practice they weren't implemented in browsers.

Some characters that are valid in names and ids must be quoted to use as CSS selectors, e.g. for:

```
<div id="d[]">
```

the CSS selector is:

```
#d\[\]
```

and for use with the Selectors API:

```
#d\\[\\]
```

(e.g. `document.querySelector('#d\\[\\]')`.

> Are both case-sensitive?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title: Yes, whenever the syntax of an element allows a `name` attribute, its value may be identical with the `id` attribute value. This follows from the declarations of the `name` attribute: its value is any string, and the only constraint imposed relates to the `a` element; and for it, the requirement is that the `name` attribute value must not match the `id` attribute value of *another* element (but *must* match the `id` attribute value of the *same* element if present).

To address the assumptions in the question: The `name` attribute in *form field* elements is indeed primarily for server-side processing; but various other elements may have a `name` attribute, for different uses. The `id` attribute is helpful in client-side programming, but it also has the effect of creating a destination anchor so that the element can be referred to by a link in the same document or another document. There is technically no tag that “needs” both `id` and `name`, or even one of them; whether they are used depends on practical purposes. The `name` attribute is *not* required to be unique, and it is not meant to provide unique identification. You can, for example, have an arbitrary amount of `input` elements with the same `name` attribute.

The syntax of `id` has traditionally been restricted in HTML specifications, but browsers have been much more permissive, and HTML5 PR imposes no other restrictions than the following: the value must not be empty (i.e. it must contain at least one character), it must not contain space characters, and it must be unique within the document (i.e. no two elements can have the same `id` attribute value).

The syntax of `name` has always been free. Apart from the special rules for the `a` element, the only restriction is that the value must not be empty.

Both `id` and `name` attribute values are case-sensitive. The special rules for the `a` element impose restrictions involving case-insensitivity, for legacy reasons.

There are many possible reasons why you might want to make `id` and `name` different for an element. For example, when interfacing to an existing server-side script that requires very long and complicated names for the fields, you have to use them in `name` attributes, but you are free to choose your `id` attributes.

The choices made when writing `id` and `name` attribute values have their consequences, but they depend on the contexts where the values are used. For example, if an `id` attribute value starts with a digit, it cannot be directly used in a CSS selector due to CSS syntax (but must be escaped). Similarly, the ways you can use the values in JavaScript depend on the syntax you have used, but you can always refer to them *some* way.

Answer (score 1):

name attribute usually doesn't need to be unique. A given HTML document may have several forms, and each of them might have elements having names identical to names in the other forms.

If you're using PHP, saying:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="foo[]" />
  <input type="text" name="foo[]" />
</form>
```

would cause, PHP to read this name as array and all entries will contained within it. Names could possibly be used as attributes for non-form elements, however, they're most frequently used only within form.

id attribute on the other hand, needs to be able to uniquely identify a given DOM element within the document. You're not forced to use it this way. Browser doesn't blow up if you use same id on two different elements. But if you have two elements with same id, the last one you add prevails over the previous ones. So,

```
document.getElementById( 'foo' )
// or 
$( '#foo' )
```

will return just one element of several.

id can be used to identify any element within the document and is not constrained to be within a form